# Excel: get last and previous non-blank value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to get the last and the before-last non-blank cell value of a row, like this:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Can you please tell me how to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

For the last:

```
=INDEX(D2:O2,AGGREGATE(14,7,(COLUMN(D2:O2)-MIN(COLUMN(D2:O2))+1)/(D2:O2<>""),1))
```

For the 2nd to last:

```
=INDEX(D2:O2,AGGREGATE(14,7,(COLUMN(D2:O2)-MIN(COLUMN(D2:O2))+1)/(D2:O2<>""),2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the months are each stored as dates and formatted to months only, you can use the following two formulas:

#### LAST

```
=xlookup(maxifs(RowOfMonths;RowOfValues;concatenate("<>";""))RowOfMonths;RowOfValues)
```

#### PREVIOUS

```
=xlookup(maxifs(RowOfMonths;RowOfValues;concatenate("<>";""),RowOfMonths;concatenate("<";maxifs(RowOfMonths;RowOfValues;concatenate("<>";"")));RowOfMonths;RowOfValues))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase you're interested here's a VBA solution.

```
Option Explicit

  Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$D$2:$O$2")) Is Nothing Then
  
      [B2] = Cells(2, "P").End(xlToLeft).Value
      [A2] = Cells(2, "P").End(xlToLeft).End(xlToLeft).Value

    End If
    
End Sub
```

HTH